# Changing UICollectionview cell XY position - swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, xcode8

I'm using a UICollectionview with XX cells. How can i change the XY position on every single cell programmatically? I can change the size of every cell with:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Is there another function like above that changes the XY positioning?

Comment: You would propably need to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` or `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and implement your custom layouting there. What is your exact use case? Maybe it can be achieved by tweaking the layout parameters? Did you look at [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout) documentation?

Comment: I have gone over the docs 100 times. I'm new to swift, so making any "custom" subclass of anything will be very time consuming. BUT i'm willing to learn, if you can point me in the right direction i will be very thankful :)

Comment: Use case: 24 images with custom locations on a blank white canvas/poster. User can change the position, images, etc.

Comment: Ah, ok. I wouldn't use a `UICollectionView` for this - this control is more about a somehow structured layout. I'd rather add 24 individual `UIImageView`s with `UIGestureRecognizer`s to enable moving/scaling/rotating. This will give you total freedom to place the images however you want.

Comment: The images can vary from 2 to 24 pictures. So i just add imageviews programmatically?

Comment: That's how I'd approach it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example will help you. Let me explain this code blocks. You can think standard UICollectionView and Cell design. There is no detailView. This code implementation will create parallax effect HeaderView.

**FIRST AND FOREMOST**

```
import UIKit

class DIYLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {

  var deltaY: CGFloat = 0

  override func copy(with zone: NSZone?) -> Any {
    let copy = super.copy(with: zone) as! DIYLayoutAttributes
    copy.deltaY = deltaY
    return copy
  }

  override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
    if let attributes = object as? DIYLayoutAttributes {
      if attributes.deltaY == deltaY {
        return super.isEqual(object)
      }
    }
    return false
  }

}

class DIYLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    var maximumStretchHeight: CGFloat = 0

    override class var layoutAttributesClass : AnyClass {
        return DIYLayoutAttributes.self
    }


  override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    // Create layout attributes
    let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) as! [DIYLayoutAttributes]

    // How far user scrollview.
    let insets = collectionView!.contentInset
    let offset = collectionView!.contentOffset

    let minY = -insets.top

    // we need the calculate delta.
    if (offset.y < minY) {
      let deltaY = fabs(offset.y - minY)

        // we can loop through all attributes
      for attributes in layoutAttributes {

        //Manipulate attributes
        if let elementKind = attributes.representedElementKind {
          if elementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
            // create frame.
            var frame = attributes.frame
            frame.size.height = max(minY, headerReferenceSize.height + deltaY)

            //We need the change origin for scrolling.
            frame.origin.y = frame.minY - deltaY
            attributes.frame = frame
            attributes.deltaY = deltaY
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return layoutAttributes
  }

    // Layout will scroll.
  override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
```

**SECOND**
You need custom cell design.

```
import UIKit

class ScheduleHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {

  @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var backgroundImageView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var backgroundImageViewHeightLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

  @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var foregroundImageView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var foregroundImageViewHeightLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


    fileprivate var backgroundImageViewHeight: CGFloat = 0
    fileprivate var foregroundImageViewHeight: CGFloat = 0
    fileprivate var previousHeight: CGFloat = 0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        backgroundImageViewHeight = backgroundImageView.bounds.height
        foregroundImageViewHeight = foregroundImageView.bounds.height
    }

        override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
            super.apply(layoutAttributes)
            let attributes = layoutAttributes as! DIYLayoutAttributes
            let height = attributes.frame.height
            if previousHeight != height {
                backgroundImageViewHeightLayoutConstraint.constant = backgroundImageViewHeight - attributes.deltaY
                foregroundImageViewHeightLayoutConstraint.constant = foregroundImageViewHeight + attributes.deltaY
                previousHeight = height
            }
        }

    }
```

**THIRD**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "ScheduleHeader", for: indexPath) as! ScheduleHeaderView
    return header
  }
```

**Of course we need to from viewDidLoad.**

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Add layout.

    let width = collectionView!.bounds.width
    let layout = collectionViewLayout as! DIYLayout
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 180)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 62)
    layout.maximumStretchHeight = width
  }
```

Comment: Wow Durul, let me try it out and return in a few days! :-)